# Macbook 2010 with OS X 10.9 - "Dangling Thumbs" issue while typing

Tags: macos, keyboard, macbook-pro, trackpad

I have a problem suddenly finding myself typing in a completely different part of a document.  I'd like to see an option to disable the trackpad while typing, for a user-selected number of ms after a keystroke.  That would solve the most irritating thing about the macbook for me.

Answer (score 1):

there used to be an option for it as seen in this article: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3608?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US
If you have a mac running mountain lion or below this still works.
There is still an option to disable tap to click in system preferences/trackpad but that disables it even when you are not typing.